# Entity Framework association with multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, associations, navigation-properties

I have the following model with 3 tables and I'm attempting to create an association to the third table CustomerPart which uses a compound key from both of the other tables.

[image: Model]

CustomerPart should be accessed via a key of CustomerNo from ShopOrder and Site/CatalogNo from SalesPart.

The only thing I've been able to come up with so far is to create an association from SalesPart to CustomerPart and in code manually select records where CustomerNo on CustomerPart matches the CustomerNo on ShopOrder.

Is there a way to create an association and navigation property for this or am I out of luck?

Comment: are you using code-first fluent api?

Comment: Unfortunately this is database first, and I can't modify the database.